# Vanilla js class factory

Tags: javascript, class, factory

I was trying to implement some kind of factory that create a class definition in the run time,I figure this work my code look like this

```
 function JsClassFactory() {
    this.X = class {

    };
    this.addMethod = (name, def) => {
        let Y = class extends this.X {
            constructor() {
                super()
                this[name] = def
            }
        }
        this.X = Y
        return this;
    }

    this.addAttribute = (name, def) => {
        return this.addMethod(name, def)
    }

    this.getClass = function () {
        return this.X
    };
}


(function () {
    const cf = new JsClassFactory()
    cf.addAttribute('age', 35)
    cf.addAttribute('name', 'chehimi')

    cf.addMethod('myName', function () {
        console.log(' i am %s', this.name)
    })
    cf.addMethod('myAge', function () {
        console.log('my age is', this.age)
    })
    let z = new (cf.getClass())
    z.myName();
    z.myAge()
    cf.addAttribute('name', 'ali')
    cf.addAttribute('age', 15)
    let t = new (cf.getClass())
    t.myName();
    t.myAge()
})()
```

i am asking if there is a better a way to implement this feature?
or a better work arround,

Comment: "better work around" in terms of performance or coding style/implementation? I think you're fine in terms of performance though the addMethod method could just return an actual (non-arrow) function referencing the 2nd parameter method and it would be less confusing to many seasoned JS devs.

Comment: do you mean checking the second parameter of addMethod against function type? I was trying to implement a fluent builder, thanks

Comment: @SteveHynding '''function JsClassFactory() {
    this.X = class {

    };
    this.addMethod = function (name, def) {
        if (typeof def !== "function") throw Error('def must be a function type');
        this.addAttribute(name, def)
    }

    this.addAttribute = function (name, def) {
        let Y = class extends this.X {
            constructor() {
                super()
                this[name] = def
            }
        }
        this.X = Y
        return this;
    }

    this.getClass = function () {
        return this.X
    };
}

Comment: Your pattern is fine if you're targeting the code for object-oriented-minded developers (coming from C# or Java, for example). Under the hood, however, JS classes are just syntactic sugar for its prototype pattern implemented in function types. I'm not saying it's incorrect or even bad practice, but it would produce some mildly-interesting discussions in code review if it came from my team.

Comment: Repeating `this.X = class extends this.X { … }` with every `addMethod` call is horrible and inefficient. Just use `this.X.prototype[name] = def;`!

Comment: Also, attributes should be added in the constructor, and their values should come from parameters of the constructor. Adding them in the factory, and creating new classes for every instance with different values, is just abhorrent.

Comment: @Bergi it dosnt work with prototype it fail in the test you cant capture the this accessor

Comment: @mohamedchehimi What test? What "*this accessor*"?

Comment: @bergi  i meant by test the code in the self invoking function

Comment: That test will have exactly the same results if you use `this.addMethod = (name, def) => { this.X.prototype[name] = def; return this; }`

Comment: @Bergi it dosnt checkout with   https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rmtxrb?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.js

Comment: @mohamedchehimi there, your `myAge` method is printing `this.name` not `this.age`. The `addAttribute` implementation works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I would take to accomplish this.

```js
class JSClassBuilder {
  constructor(){
    this.constructedClass = class {};
    this.constructedClassAttributes = {};
  }
  
  addStatic(name, definition){
    this.constructedClass[name] = definition;
    return this;
  }
  
  addAttribute(name, value){
    if(typeof definition != 'function'){
      this.constructedClassAttributes[name] = value;
      return this;
    }
    throw new TypeError("parameter value must not be of type: 'function'");
  }
  
  addMethod(name, definition){
    if(typeof definition == 'function'){
      this.constructedClass.prototype[name] = definition;
      return this;
    }
    throw new TypeError("parameter definition must be of type: 'function'");
  }
  
  constructClass(){
    return Object.assign(
      new this.constructedClass(), 
      this.constructedClassAttributes
    ); 
  }
}

const classBuilder = new JSClassBuilder();

const c = classBuilder
            .addAttribute('age', 35)
            .addAttribute('name', 'Chehimi')
            .addMethod('myName', function () {
                console.log('I am %s', this.name);
            })
            .addMethod('myAge', function () {
                console.log('I am %s', this.age);
            })
            .constructClass();
c.myName();
c.myAge();

const a = classBuilder
            .addAttribute('name', 'Ali')
            .addAttribute('age', 15)
            .constructClass();
a.myName();
a.myAge();
```